# Flownet2 pytorch installation issue

Tags: python, docker, pytorch

I was following the following tutorial [flownet2-pytorch](https://github.com/dancelogue/flownet2-pytorch) to get optical flow data from video.
However, when trying to launch the docker file (via command line: bash launch_docker.sh) I got the following error
[docker-error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMQR9.png).

Comment: Imgur links will not be there forever. Therefore, it's recommended to copy-paste the error text as code formatted text in your question body

Comment: Have you looked into the original repository or what is the reason to use a forked one? https://github.com/NVIDIA/flownet2-pytorch